# Page fails to load on 1st attempt

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I changed from a CISCO wired Cable connection to a Motorola SBP901 wireless connection... After that whenever i try to load a new page the first reply is Server not found. Then i have to hit the refresh button and then the page loads successfully... I am running Windows 7 home premium and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS issue. Your DNS is not resolving fast enough for the browser.

I would suggest changing your DNS settings on your router to use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html) servers.